# Multidimensional Brownian motion and Ito lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I am having a bit of difficulty with the following practice problem that involves multidimensional brownian motion.

With $B_t = (B_t^{(1)},B_t^{(2)})$ apply ito to the following process:

$$X_t = \exp\left(1+\int_0^t{B_s^{(1)}\, dB_s^{(2)}}\right)$$

I have tried proceeding with the differential form with the following function of $y$:

Let $Y_t = \int_0^t{B_s^{(1)}\, dB_s^{(2)}} $, $dY_t = B_t^{(1)}\, dB_t^{(2)} $,
$\langle Y\rangle_t = \left(B_t^{(1)}\right)^2 \,dt $

But I am not too sure where to proceed from here or if I am on the right track when it comes to multidimensional Ito.

Comment: Hint: Your expressions for $dY$ and $\langle Y\rangle$ are correct. Now apply Ito to $X_t=f(Y_t)$ where $f(y)=e^{1+y}\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. Is it now just a matter of finding the first and second derivative of the function $f(y)$ which is just $f(y)$ in both cases and using what I have already found to complete the differential form? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Why don't you just write down what you get for $dX$ from Ito ?

Comment: $\exp\left(1+\int_0^t{B_s^{(1)}\, dB_s^{(2)}}\right) (B_s^{(1)})^2 (dB_s^{(2)})^2 + \frac{1}{2} \exp\left(1+\int_0^t{B_s^{(1)}\, dB_s^{(2)}}\right)(B_t^{(1)})^2 dt  $

Comment: There are too many squares in your first term. The starting point should be $\exp(1+Y_t)\,dY_t+\frac{1}{2}\exp(1+Y_t)\,d\langle Y\rangle_t\,.$ Then plug it what you got for $Y_t,dY_t,d\langle Y\rangle_t\,.$